# Inequality problem: Application of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c \in (1, \infty)$ such that $ \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}=2$. Prove that:
$$
\sqrt {a-1} + \sqrt {b-1} + \sqrt {c-1} \leq \sqrt {a+b+c}.
$$
This is supposed to be solved using the [Cauchy inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality); that is, the scalar product inequality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We apply the Cauchy Schwarz Inequality to the vectors $x = \left({\sqrt {\dfrac{a-1}{a}} , \sqrt {\dfrac{b-1}{b}} , \sqrt {\dfrac{c-1}{c}}}\right) $ and $y = \left({\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{bc}},\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ac}}, \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ab}} }\right)$ in $\Bbb R^3$.

Then, $x \cdot y \le \lVert x\rVert \lVert y\rVert$ yields,

$$ \dfrac{\sqrt{a-1} + \sqrt{b-1} + \sqrt{c-1}}{\sqrt{abc}} \le \sqrt{\dfrac{a-1}{a} + \dfrac{b-1}{b} + \dfrac{c-1}{c}} \times \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{bc} + \dfrac{1}{ac} + \dfrac{1}{ab}}$$

Now manipulating the $\sqrt{abc}$ across the sign we get

$$ \sqrt{a-1} + \sqrt{b-1} + \sqrt{c-1} \le \sqrt{\dfrac{a-1}{a} + \dfrac{b-1}{b} + \dfrac{c-1}{c}} \times \sqrt{a+ b+c} $$

So, $$ \dfrac{\sqrt{a-1} + \sqrt{b-1} + \sqrt{c-1}}{\sqrt{a+ b+c}} \le \sqrt{\left({1 - \dfrac 1 a}\right) + \left({1 - \dfrac 1 b}\right) + \left({1 - \dfrac 1 c}\right) }$$

$$ \dfrac{\sqrt{a-1} + \sqrt{b-1} + \sqrt{c-1}}{\sqrt{a+ b+c}}  \le \sqrt{3 - \left({\dfrac 1 a + \dfrac 1 b + \dfrac 1 c}\right)} = \sqrt{3-2} = 1$$

$\mathscr{Q.E.D}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=x+1$, $b=y+1$ and $c=z+1$.

Hence, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positives and we need to prove that
$$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}\leq\sqrt{x+y+z+3}$$ or
$\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{xz}+\sqrt{yz}\leq\frac{3}{2}$.

But in another hand, the condition geves
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{x+1}=2$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{x+1}-1\right)=-1$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{x+1}=1.$$
Thus, by C-S
$$1=\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{x+1}\geq\frac{\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}\right)^2}{x+y+z+3},$$
which gives $\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{xz}+\sqrt{yz}\leq\frac{3}{2}$.

Done!